# I'm trying to create a PHP page that will take input and create a table containing that input

Tags: php, mysql, database, input, field

as the title says I'm struggling with accomplishing this. So far I've managed to connect to the database and create tables, but I'm having a hard time getting the input field to communicate with the PHP in order to communicate the variable. Below is my code, any help is appreciated:

```
<html>
<input type="text" name="firstname" />
</html>

<?php
$dbserver= "localhost";
$dbuser= "nyamamot_live";
$dbpass = "co6}]oJ5Db9v";
$dbname = "nyamamot_live";

//conncet
$conn = new mysqli($dbserver, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
//check
if ($conn->connect_error) {
   die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// make vars
$tablename = "MyTable";
$col1 = "col1";


$firstname = $_POST["firstname"];


// sql to create table
$sql = "CREATE TABLE $tablename (
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
$firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(50),
reg_date TIMESTAMP
)";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Table MyGuests created successfully\n";
} else {
    echo "Error creating table: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();

?>
```

Comment: You're not actually submitting the form.

Answer (score 2):

You need a button and an action  for your form and then test to make sure it is submitted before running your code:

```
<html>
    <form name="myform" action="myphp.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="firstname" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" />
    </form>
</html>
```

Then test:

```
if(isset($_POST['firstname']) && '' != $_POST['firstname']){

    $dbserver= "localhost";
    $dbuser= "nyamamot_live";
    $dbpass = "co6}]oJ5Db9v";
    $dbname = "nyamamot_live";

//conncet
    $conn = new mysqli($dbserver, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
//check
   if ($conn->connect_error) {
       die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

// make vars
    $tablename = "MyTable";
    $col1 = "col1";


    $firstname = $_POST["firstname"];


// sql to create table
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE $tablename (
    id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    $firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(50),
    reg_date TIMESTAMP
    )";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "Table MyGuests created successfully\n";
    } else {
        echo "Error creating table: " . $conn->error;
    }

    $conn->close();
}
```

You will also want to make sure your table creation syntax is correct and any variables you consume in the statement are cleansed and handled properly.

Comment: Looks good! Person who asked the question must understand that "myphp.php" is the file name where this code is written, else you can use action="" to come to the same page.

Comment: Perfect! This works exactly as intended, thank you for pointing out the form and the isset thing. I'll do some more research to figure out exactly what each of these mean, you've given me somewhere to start.